# Highlight ListView row based on id

Tags: android, listview, listadapter

How can I highlight a row in a ListView backed by a CursorAdapter knowing the row ID of the item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "highlight" you mean "select", you will need to manually iterate over your `Cursor`, find which position corresponds to that `_id` value, then call `setSelection()` on the `ListView` to select the row with that position. This will only have an impact if the user is not in touch mode, as there is no concept of a selection in a `ListView` if the user is using the touch screen.

**EDIT**

Given your first comment, you will need to do several things:

1. Extend your existing adapter class to create your own custom one
2. Override `getViewTypeCount()` to return `2`, since you have two types of rows (normal and special)
3. Override `getItemViewType()` to return `0` or `1`, depending on whether the position is the one for your desired `_id` or not
4. Override `bindView()` and based on the item view type, inflate and tailor the row as needed

Comment: I mean make the row stand out from the others in any way possible.